# arduino nano broken or not after reversing l7805 pins?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, pins

I tried to breadboard a project using arduino nano and l7805 regulator power by 12v dc from wall. I pluged the regulator backwards, output to 12v and input to 5v arduino pin, by mistake for a couple of seconds and I think I destroyed the arduino. Now the blink sketch that was uploaded is not workink and when I try to upload it again it says avr not in sync.  The power led is on and also the ftdi chip is recognised by windows.  Is it possible I detroyed it or not? What happened when I reversed the regulators pins?

Comment: Something has probably been destroyed. If you are lucky it is eg a shorted tantalum power supply capacitor, but it is likely that the damage is more general. A reversed regulator may act as a diode and pass the 12V through to the "output". Look for power supply filter capacitors. Removing them with correct supply voltage MAY restore operation. May :-(.

Comment: Chances are it's toast.  You may be able to rescue it if you replace most of the components. More than likely the main chip is dead.

Comment: I went off without a blast. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the circuit of a 7805 regulator there are a number of possible current paths that would feed current from the 'output' to the 'input' if you have reversed the connections.

[image]

This may (or may not) not damage the 7805 depending on the size of current taken through the device but there's a high probability that the supply voltage the arduino experienced would be the full 12V. There's a good chance it has been (partially) damaged.

Comment: I think the 7805 is not damaged. It still otputs 5v. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @PetracheValentin Russell also makes a good point below about capacitors (+1 from me).

Answer (score 1):

Something has probably been destroyed. If you are lucky it is eg a shorted tantalum power supply capacitor, but it is likely that the damage is more general. A reversed regulator may act as a diode and pass the 12V through to the "output". Look for power supply filter capacitors. Removing them with correct supply voltage MAY restore operation. May :-(.

Any electrolytic capacitors at the points circled in red MAY have gone short circuit with excess voltage - usually tantalum capacitors will do this but other types usually won't.

[image]

Comment: Yup. The parts are smd and I think I`ll just go with another arduino or just a atmega microcontroller. Thanks a lot for the answer.